# $f(x)^3+g(x)^3+h(x)^3=1$ relation with elliptic integrals

Tags: functions, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

$x\in\mathbb{C}$  and $f,g,h:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$

$f,g,h$ are Meromorphic functions.

$$f(x)^3+g(x)^3+h(x)^3=1  \tag{1}$$
$$f'(x)=g(x)^2-h(x)^2  \tag{2}$$
$$g'(x)=h(x)^2-f(x)^2 \tag{3}$$

Initial conditions: $f(0)=m$,  $g(0)=n$

---

We have 3 unknown functions, and we also have 3 different equations .
I would like to find out $f(x),g(x),h(x),$

If we derivative Equation $(1)$ ,we can get

$$3f(x)^2f'(x)+3g(x)^2g'(x)+3h(x)^2h'(x)=0  $$

$$h'(x)=f(x)^2-g(x)^2 \tag{4}$$

It can be shown easily from sum of Equation (2), (3) , (4) that

$$f'(x)+g'(x)+h'(x)=0 $$

If we integrate it,

$$f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=k$$

and put  $x=0$

$$f(0)+g(0)+h(0)=k$$

$k=m+n+(1-(m^3+n^3))^\frac{1}{3}$

I would like to find differential equation for $f(x),g(x),h(x) $

Using Equation $(2)$ and apply derivative both sides
$$f''(x)=2g'(x)g(x)-2h'(x)h(x)$$
$$f''(x)=2g(x)(h(x)^2-f(x)^2)-2h(x)(f(x)^2-g(x)^2)$$

$$f''(x)=2(g(x)h(x)-f(x)^2)(g(x)+h(x))$$
$$f''(x)=2(k-f(x))(g(x)h(x)-f(x)^2) \tag {5}$$

If we use Equation (2)
$$f'(x)=(g(x)-h(x))(g(x)+h(x))   $$
$$f'(x)=(g(x)-h(x))(k-f(x))   $$

$$g(x)-h(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{k-f(x)}   $$

$$g(x)+h(x)=k-f(x)$$

$$2g(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{k-f(x)} +k-f(x)$$

$$g(x)=\frac{f'(x)+(k-f(x))^2}{2(k-f(x))} $$
$$h(x)=\frac{(k-f(x))^2-f'(x)}{2(k-f(x))} $$

If we put $g(x),h(x)$ in Equation (5)

$$f''(x)=2(k-f(x))(\frac{(k-f(x))^4-f'(x)^2}{4(k-f(x))^2}-f(x)^2) \tag {6}$$

$$2f''(x) (k-f(x)) +f'(x)^2 =(k-f(x))^4-4f(x)^2(k-f(x))^2 \tag {7}$$

Let's assume that the solution of the differential equation is :

$$f'(x)^2=(f(x)^2-k^2)^2+c(f(x)-k)  \tag{8}$$
Where c is another constant

The Proof of my assumption above:

$$2 f'(x)f''(x)=4(f(x)^2-k^2)f(x)f'(x)+cf'(x)$$

$$2 f''(x)=4(f(x)^2-k^2)f(x)+c$$

Multiply both side by $ (k-f(x))$

$$2 f''(x)(k-f(x))=4(f(x)^2-k^2)(k-f(x))f(x)+c(k-f(x))  \tag{9}$$

If we add Equation $(8)$ and $(9)$,

$$2 f''(x)(k-f(x))+f'(x)^2=4(f(x)^2-k^2)(k-f(x))f(x)+(f(x)^2-k^2)^2$$
$$2 f''(x)(k-f(x))+f'(x)^2=(f(x)^2-k^2)[4(k-f(x))f(x)+(f(x)^2-k^2)]$$

$$2 f''(x)(k-f(x))+f'(x)^2=(f(x)^2-k^2)(k-f(x))[4f(x)-f(x)-k)]$$

$$2 f''(x)(k-f(x))+f'(x)^2=(f(x)^2-k^2)(k-f(x))(3f(x)-k)$$

$$2 f''(x)(k-f(x))+f'(x)^2=(k-f(x))^4-4f(x)^2(k-f(x))^2$$

It proves that my assumption is true in Equation $(8)$

Solution for $f(x)$  can be written as

$$f'(x)^2=(f(x)^2-k^2)^2+c_1(f(x)-k)  $$
$$ x=\int_{f(0)}^{f(x)} \frac{du}{\sqrt{(u^2-k^2)^2+c_1(u-k)}}$$

It is an elliptic function and we apply the same procedure for $g(x)$ and $h(x)$  same result we will get

$$ x=\int_{g(0)}^{g(x)} \frac{du}{\sqrt{(u^2-k^2)^2+c_2(u-k)}}$$

$$ x=\int_{h(0)}^{h(x)} \frac{du}{\sqrt{(u^2-k^2)^2+c_3(u-k)}}$$

If we derivative all $f(x)$ $g(x)$ and $h(x)$

$$\frac{f'(x)}{(\sqrt{f(x)^2-k^2)^2+c_1(f(x)-k)}}=\frac{g'(x)}{\sqrt{(g(x)^2-k^2)^2+c_2(g(x)-k)}}=\frac{h'(x)}{\sqrt{(h(x)^2-k^2)^2+c_3(h(x)-k)}}=1$$
Where $c_1,c_2,c_3$  are constants

My Question:

1. Are $f(x)$ $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ doubly periodic functions?
2. What are their period formulas if they are doubly periodic functions ?
3. Can We express the $f(x)$ $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ as the Weierstrass Elliptic function?

It is very nice result but I have not expected to have such result .Please write comments about your analyzes why the result is elliptic integral  for cubic sum equation? I believe my method can be extended for 
$$f(x)^n+g(x)^n+h(x)^n=1 $$ 
$$f'(x)=g(x)^{n-1}-h(x)^{n-1}$$
$$g'(x)=h(x)^{n-1}-f(x)^{n-1}$$
where n is positive integer $n>3$. Please share if you find some elliptic integrals for $n>3$

Thanks a lot for answers and comments

EDIT: I have proved that $c_1=c_2=c_3$

Proof:

$f(0)=m$,  $g(0)=n$  ,
$$f(0)+g(0)+h(0)=k$$
$$k=m+n+(1-(m^3+n^3))^\frac{1}{3}$$

$$h(0)=k-(m+n)$$

Let's define $$h(0)=k-(m+n)=r$$

$$\frac{f'(x)}{(\sqrt{f(x)^2-k^2)^2+c_1(f(x)-k)}}=1$$

$$f'(x)^2=(f(x)^2-k^2)^2+c_1(f(x)-k)  $$

$$f'(x)^2-(f(x)^2-k^2)^2=c_1(f(x)-k)  $$

$x=0$

$$f'(0)^2-(f(0)^2-k^2)^2=c_1(f(0)-k)  $$

$$[f'(0)+(f(0)^2-k^2)][f'(0)-(f(0)^2-k^2)]=c_1(f(0)-k)  $$

$$[\frac{f'(0)}{(f(0)-k)}+f(0)+k][f'(0)-f(0)^2+k^2]=c_1  $$
$$[\frac{n^2-r^2}{(-(n+r)}+m+m+n+r][n^2-r^2-m^2+(m+n+r)^2]=c_1$$

$$[-n+r+m+m+n+r][n^2-r^2-m^2+m^2+n^2+r^2+2mn+2mr+2rn]=c_1$$
$$2[m+r][2n^2+2mn+2mr+2rn]=c_1$$
$$c_1=4(m+r)(n+m)(n+r)$$

$c_1$ is symmetric , It means if we do the same actions for  $g(x),h(x)$,

we will find same $c_1=c_2=c_3=4(m+r)(n+m)(n+r)$

If we write as k value,
$$c_1=c_2=c_3=4(m+r)(n+m)(n+r)=c$$

$$c=4(m+k-m-n)(n+m)(n+k-n-m)$$
$$c=4(k-n)(n+m)(k-m)$$

$$\frac{f'(x)}{(\sqrt{f(x)^2-k^2)^2+c(f(x)-k)}}=\frac{g'(x)}{\sqrt{(g(x)^2-k^2)^2+c(g(x)-k)}}=\frac{h'(x)}{\sqrt{(h(x)^2-k^2)^2+c(h(x)-k)}}=1$$

$$ x=\int_{f(0)}^{f(x)} \frac{du}{\sqrt{(u^2-k^2)^2+c(u-k)}}$$
$$ x=\int_{g(0)}^{g(x)} \frac{du}{\sqrt{(u^2-k^2)^2+c(u-k)}}$$

$$ x=\int_{h(0)}^{h(x)} \frac{du}{\sqrt{(u^2-k^2)^2+c(u-k)}}$$

$$ x=\int_{m}^{f(x)} \frac{du}{\sqrt{(u^2-(m+n+r)^2)^2+4(m+n)(m+r)(r+n)(u-(m+n+r))}}=\int_{n}^{g(x)} \frac{du}{\sqrt{(u^2-(m+n+r)^2)^2+4(m+n)(m+r)(r+n)(u-(m+n+r))}}=\int_{r}^{h(x)} \frac{du}{\sqrt{(u^2-(m+n+r)^2)^2+4(m+n)(m+r)(r+n)(u-(m+n+r))}}$$

EDIT: I have found an easy way how to produce differential equations

$$f(x)^p+g(x)^p+h(x)^p=1 $$ 
$$f'(x)=g(x)^{p-1}-h(x)^{p-1}$$
$$g'(x)=h(x)^{p-1}-f(x)^{p-1}$$
and we can find other relations as I showed above  that
$$h'(x)=f(x)^{p-1}-g(x)^{p-1}$$
$$f'(x)+g'(x)+h'(x)=0 $$

$$f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=k $$ 
where p is positive integer . $k$ is a constant.

$p=2$

$$f(x)^2+g(x)^2+h(x)^2=1 $$ 
$$f(x)^2+(g(x)+h(x))^2-2g(x)h(x)=1 $$ 
$$f(x)^2+(k-f(x))^2-2g(x)h(x)=1 $$

$$2g(x)h(x)=1-f(x)^2-k^2+2kf(x)-f(x)^2=1-k^2+2kf(x)-2f(x)^2 $$ 
$$g(x)h(x)=\frac{1-k^2}{2}+kf(x)-f(x)^2$$

$$f'(x)^2=g(x)-h(x)$$
$$f'(x)^2=(g(x)+h(x))^2-4g(x)h(x)$$

$$f'(x)^2=(k-f(x))^2-2(1-k^2)+4kf(x)-4f(x)^2$$
$$f'(x)^2=k^2-2kf(x)+f(x)^2+2(1-k^2)+4kf(x)-4f(x)^2$$
$$f'(x)^2=-3f(x)^2+2kf(x)+2-k^2$$

If both side derivate, 
$$f''(x)+3f(x)=k$$

General solution for $p=2$

$f(0)=m$ ,$g(0)=n$ , $h(0)=r$ 
$$m^2+n^2+r^2=1$$
$$m+n+r=k$$

$$f(x)=\frac{m+n+r}{3}+\frac{2m-(n+r)}{3}\cos( \sqrt{3}x)+\frac{(n-r)}{\sqrt{3}}\sin( \sqrt{3}x)$$
$$g(x)=\frac{m+n+r}{3}+\frac{2n-(m+r)}{3}\cos( \sqrt{3}x)+\frac{(r-m)}{\sqrt{3}}\sin( \sqrt{3}x)$$
$$h(x)=\frac{m+n+r}{3}+\frac{2r-(m+n)}{3}\cos( \sqrt{3}x)+\frac{(m-n)}{\sqrt{3}}\sin( \sqrt{3}x)$$

---

$p=3$

$$f(x)^3+g(x)^3+h(x)^3=1 $$ 
$$f(x)^3+(g(x)+h(x))^3-3g(x)h(x)(g(x)+h(x))=1 $$ 
$$f(x)^3+(k-f(x))^3-3g(x)h(x)(k-f(x))=1 $$

$$k^3-3k^2f(x)+3kf(x)^2-3g(x)h(x)(k-f(x))=1$$ 
$$-3kf(x)(k-f(x))+k^3-1=3g(x)h(x)(k-f(x))$$ 
$$g(x)h(x)=-kf(x)+\frac{k^3-1}{3(k-f(x))}$$

$$f''(x)=2g'(x)g(x)-2h'(x)h(x)$$
$$f''(x)=2g(x)(h(x)^2-f(x)^2)-2h(x)(f(x)^2-g(x)^2)$$

$$f''(x)=2(g(x)h(x)-f(x)^2)(g(x)+h(x))$$
$$f''(x)=2(-kf(x)+\frac{k^3-1}{3(k-f(x))}-f(x)^2)(k-f(x))$$

$$f''(x)=2(-kf(x)+\frac{k^3-1}{3(k-f(x))}-f(x)^2)(k-f(x))$$
$$f''(x)=2(-kf(x)(k-f(x))+\frac{k^3-1}{3}-f(x)^2(k-f(x)))$$

$$f''(x)=2f(x)^3-2k^2f(x)+\frac{2(k^3-1)}{3}$$

if we put $k=m+n+r$ as shown above we can get the same  differential Equation that I found above

Let's check out $p=4$

$$f(x)^4+g(x)^4+h(x)^4=1 $$ 
$$f(x)^4+(g(x)+h(x))^4-4g(x)h(x)(g(x)^2+h(x)^2)-6g(x)^2h(x)^2=1 $$ 
$$f(x)^4+(k-f(x))^4-4g(x)h(x)((k-f(x))^2-2g(x)h(x))-6g(x)^2h(x)^2=1 $$ 
$$f(x)^4+(k-f(x))^4-4g(x)h(x)(k-f(x))^2+2g(x)^2h(x)^2=1  \tag{12} $$

$$f'(x)=g(x)^3-h(x)^3$$
$$f''(x)=3g'(x)g(x)^2-3h'(x)h(x)^2$$
$$f''(x)=3g(x)^2(h(x)^3-f(x)^3)-3h(x)^2(f(x)^3-g(x)^3)$$

$$f''(x)=3g(x)^2h(x)^2(h(x)+g(x))-3f(x)^3(h(x)^2+g(x)^2)$$

$$f''(x)=3g(x)^2h(x)^2(k-f(x))-3f(x)^3((h(x)+g(x))^2-2g(x)h(x))$$

$$f''(x)=3g(x)^2h(x)^2(k-f(x))-3f(x)^3((k-f(x))^2-2g(x)h(x)) $$
$$f''(x)= -3f(x)^3((k-f(x))^2+3g(x)^2h(x)^2(k-f(x))+6g(x)h(x)f(x)^3 \tag{13} $$

I just need to combine Equation (12)  and (13) and cancel $g(x)h(x)$ but I noticed that the result looks ugly . It is not nice like $p=2$ and $p=3$. Maybe I need to check $f'''(x)=a_0+a_1f(x)+....a_nf(x)^n$ for polynomial result for differential equation. Is there any idea to organize better way? I have not found general formula yet for when $p$ is any integer. Maybe someone can see a way for general case too. Thanks a lot for helps and advice.

Comment: I get stuck in your first sentence. You say "Let's define...", but then you write down three equations, not any definitions. Are you looking for solutions of these equations? What kind of functions? Meromorphic? Why should these equations have solutions?

Comment: @LukasGeyer I edited my post. Thanks a lot for your comment. Please let me know if I need to clarify something else. Best Regards

Comment: Thanks, this makes much more sense now. Just curious, where did this system of equations come up?

Comment: @LukasGeyer I wanted to extend circular functions but in symmetric way. Circular functions f=sin(x) and g=cos(x) satisfy $f^2+g^2=1$ and $f′=g$ but If we derivative $f^2+g^2=1$,  we can get $g′=−f$. It is not same $g′=f$  I wanted to setup  function equations that when we replace any function with other one , same look will be gotten.   $$f(x)^3+g(x)^3+h(x)^3=1  $$
$$f'(x)=g(x)^2-h(x)^2  $$
$$g'(x)=h(x)^2-f(x)^2 $$ 

and also produced $h'(x)=f(x)^2-g(x)^2$
They will satisfy same differential equation but just with different initial conditions. Thanks a lot for your comments. Best Regards